# Yii2 всплывающее/скрывающееся боковое меню

Tags: javascript, html, css, yii2, bootstrap

Начал изучать фреймворк Yii2.

Хочу сделать боковое меню, которое появлялось бы при клике. Как, например, на [тостере](https://toster.ru/). Там при увеличении масштаба страницы боковое меню исчезает, и появляется значок, при клике на него меню появляется.

Я хочу сделать, чтобы меню всегда была скрыто.

Например, меню хейдера в шаблоне на Yii2 реализовано следующим образом:

```html
<?php
    NavBar::begin([
        'brandLabel' => 'My Company',
        'brandUrl' => Yii::$app->homeUrl,
        'options' => [
            'class' => 'navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top',
        ],
    ]);
    $menuItems = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
    ];
    if (Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Signup', 'url' => ['/site/signup']];
        $menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['/site/login']];
    } else {
        $menuItems[] = '<li>'
            . Html::beginForm(['/site/logout'], 'post')
            . Html::submitButton(
                'Logout (' . Yii::$app->user->identity->username . ')',
                ['class' => 'btn btn-link logout']
            )
            . Html::endForm()
            . '</li>';
    }
    echo Nav::widget([
        'options' => ['class' => 'navbar-nav navbar-right'],
        'items' => $menuItems,
    ]);
    NavBar::end();
?>
```

В общем, вопрос:

Как инструментами Yii2, Bootstrap реализовать такое меню?
Рылся в интернете, толком ничего не нашел.

Могу, конечно, написать всплывающее/скрывающееся боковое меню с нуля (HTML+CSS+JS), но боюсь изобрести велосипед.

Comment: Yii2 здесь вообще не при чём

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос касается исключительно верстки. Так как в yii2 по умолчанию подключен bootstrap, то и делать проще на bootstrap. Крайне советую прочитать всю документацию, особенно про [grid>>](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)
Так например:

```
<div class="mymenuha hidden-xs col-sm-4"></div>
```

Будет скрыт на маленьких дисплеях и совсем не важно, что в нем. Хоть меню, хоть калькулятор дырок в сыре, хоть фотография трансформатора.
Для того что бы по клику на какую-то кнопку делать его видимым, юзаем jquery, достаточно убирать class hidden-xs, например:

```
$('.mySuperButton').on('click',function(){
$('.mymenuha').toggleClass('hidden-xs');
});
```

Как видите не слова о yii. Тут вопрос знаний css, bootstrap и jquery только. Прежде чем использовать yii2, крайне рекомендую хотя бы немного разобраться с ними.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю такой вариант:
С помощью [kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-sidenav) делате сам сайднав:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['left_menu_condensed']) && (htmlentities($_COOKIE['left_menu_condensed']) == 'true')){
  $leftMenuClass = 'condensed';
  $contentContainerClass = 'expanded';
}else{
   $leftMenuClass = $contentContainerClass = '';
}

?>
<div class="wrap">
<a href="#" id="left-menu-toggle" class="<?= $leftMenuClass ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i></a>
<div id="left-menu" class="<?= $leftMenuClass ?>">
    <?php
    $path = Yii::$app->request->pathInfo;
    echo SideNav::widget([
        'type' => SideNav::TYPE_DEFAULT,
        'heading' => 'Админ панель',
        'items' => [
            [
                'url' => '/',
                'label' => 'Главная',
                'icon' => 'home',
                'active' => ($path == '')
            ],
            [
                'url' => '/clients',
                'label' => 'Клиенты',
                'icon' => 'briefcase',
                'active' => ($path == '/clients')
            ],
            //...
      ],
    ]);
    ?>
</div>
<div id="ex-container" class="<?= $contentContainerClass ?>">
   //контент
</div>
```

[image: scr]

И добавляете js для переключения меню со своими стилями.

*В снипете использована верстка "как есть", и приведена лишь для визуального примера, не копируйте слепо, модифицируйте под себя.*

```js
var leftMenu = document.querySelector('#left-menu');
var leftMenuToggle = document.querySelector('#left-menu-toggle');
var contentContainer = document.querySelector('#ex-container');

if (leftMenuToggle) {
  leftMenuToggle.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (leftMenuToggle.classList.contains('condensed')) {
      leftMenuToggle.classList.remove('condensed');
      leftMenu.classList.remove('condensed');
      contentContainer.classList.remove('expanded');
      document.cookie = "left_menu_condensed=false; path=/";
    } else {
      leftMenuToggle.classList.add('condensed');
      leftMenu.classList.add('condensed');
      contentContainer.classList.add('expanded');
      document.cookie = "left_menu_condensed=true; path=/";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
#ex-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 220px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: margin .3s;
  background-color: rgb(244, 248, 251);
}

#left-menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 220px;
  min-width: 220px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: #354052;
  transition: left .3s;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#left-menu.condensed {
  left: -220px;
}

#left-menu-toggle.condensed {
  left: 0;
  opacity: .8;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

#ex-container.expanded {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#left-menu-toggle {
  position: fixed;
  left: 164px;
  height: 37px;
  width: 56px;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #414f67;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  transition: left .3s;
}

#left-menu .panel .panel-heading {
  color: #FAFBFB;
  background-color: #414f67;
  border-color: #414f67;
}

#left-menu .panel li {
  background-color: #414f67;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.nav>li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#left-menu .panel .nav-pills li.active:nth-child(1)>a,
#left-menu .panel .nav-pills li.active:nth-child(1)>a:hover,
#left-menu .panel .nav-pills li.active:nth-child(1)>a:focus {
  color: #FAFBFB;
  background-color: #2b3340;
}

.panel-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
}

.panel-heading {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <a href="#" id="left-menu-toggle" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i>=</a>
  <div id="left-menu" class="">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Админ панель</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="table">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked kv-sidenav">
          <li class="active"><a href="/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> &nbsp;Главная</a></li>
          <li><a href="/clients"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span> &nbsp;Клиенты</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="ex-container" class="">
  <p>Какой-то контент...</p>
  <p>Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Proin eget tortor risus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Praesent sapien massa, convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. Quisque velit nisi, pretium ut lacinia in, elementum id enim.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```